# Aerospike aql: Periods in Namespace Name

Tags: aerospike

We have namespaces with periods in their names.  E.g. `budget.region1`.

How can we use `aql` to query these namespaces?

`aql` uses periods to delimit namespace from set, and appears to be confused by the periods in our namespace name:

```
aql> select * from budget.region1
Error: (20) AEROSPIKE_ERR_NAMESPACE_NOT_FOUND
```

We have tried single and double quotes around the namespace name, backslash-escaping the period, etc., with no luck.

Is `aql` usable with our namespaces?

(Answers that ask us to use client libraries (Python, Go, etc.) are not useful.  We're asking about the command line client.  Since `ascli` is deprecated/gone, we're forced to use `aql`.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, aql does not parse namespaces containing periods.  I recommend logging a bug with Aerospike.